# better way to create a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string as follows:

"This is @awesome @dude"

From this string i want to extract awesome and dude and create a string

```
 output==> "awesome,dude"
```

So my code is like following:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(textStr);
while (matcher.find()){
    mergedStr += matcher.group() +",";
}
```

But this creates an artifact in the end

```
output==> "awesome,dude,"  //<-- egghh comma.. in the end
```

What is a better way to solve this out.

Comment: You're adding the extra comma with the mergedStr += matcher.group() +","; line.

Comment: The problem is not on the regex, just on the way you build the result.

Comment: Well, you can either truncate the extraneous comma or never add it in the first place.  One way to do the latter is to do the first word outside the loop, then add the comma at the top of the loop.

Comment: @rajah9 the question is about how to not add that extra comma at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(textStr);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (!mergedStr.isEmpty())
      mergedStr += ",";
    mergedStr += matcher.group();
}
```

Comment: +1 for this simple solution but please avoid if statements without curly brackets. It is a quite bad practice.

Comment: That solves the problem, but I think this would be a better answer if you mentioned that (s)he should use a `StringBuilder`. :-)

Comment: @adenoyelle I think I'll keep my 1-line if-statements without curly brackets, I'm generally against curly brackets anywhere. But it's all just opinions.

Comment: @Dukeling if you want to avoid curly brackets why not put the *THEN* part of the statement on the same line as the *IF* part? (Im not a wild fan of that either but it is at least less easy to misread)

Comment: @RichardTingle Because I find that more difficult to read - somewhere in the middle of the line the THEN part starts (so I have to look for it), rather than 1 "tab" from the `if` (then I can instantly see it). But **this is not really the place to discuss coding standards or to not upvote people** (@adenoyelle (apologies if that was an incorrect assumption)) **because they don't conform to your coding standards**, but you would've if they had.

Comment: @ruakh Fair point, but for all but the most performance-critical task, I find it to be a micro-optimization. I'd rather stick to slightly simpler code. Not to mention that the optimizer may actually be able to convert the one to the other.

Comment: @Dukeling: I usually consider `StringBuilder` to be a micro-optimization, but when you're actually assembling a `String` in a loop, then it's the way to go. I doubt that (as you put it) "the optimizer may actually be able to convert the one to the other", since that would (for example) require translating `mergeStr.isEmpty()` to `mergeStringBuilder.length() == 0`.

Comment: @ruakh Ok, it might not be a micro-optimization as such in this case, but, in my experience, it is very likely that the rest of the program will take a lot longer or the program doesn't have the performance requirement to justify complicating it. And `isEmpty` just does `return value.length == 0`, which, in my opinion, makes it a minor conversion. I don't know if it actually does convert it, just that it shouldn't be difficult for it to do.

Comment: @Dukeling: When you're building a `String` in a loop, I don't think that `StringBuilder` is actually "complicating it", so much as it's simply making clear the intent. (Would you consider it a "micro-optimization" to use `HashMap<String,String>` instead of `List<Map.Entry<String,String>>` as a map?)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
boolean needComma = false;
while (blah, blah, blah) {
    if (needComma) {
        string += ",";
    }
    string += word;
    needComma = true;
}
```

But there are a dozen different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another common approach:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(textStr);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()){
    sb.append(matcher.group()).append(",");
}
return sb.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");
```

---

If you don't want to use a regex, you could do it like this:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(textStr);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()){
    sb.append(matcher.group()).append(",");
}
if (sb.length() == 0) {
    return "";
}
else {
    return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Does not work because String.replace does not accept regular expressions. If you use replaceAll instead, it works.

Comment: Good point... Not sure how I forgot that (too much JavaScript lately).  Corrected.

Comment: `return mergedStr.substring(0, mergedStr.length()-1);` may be a better option.

Comment: @Dukeling - That would not work if the StringBuilder is empty... Otherwise I would have used it.  The choice was to add an if/else (plus braces;) or to use a regex.  Obviously there are about a dozen common ways that this situation is handled.

Comment: Oh, right, forgot about that. `return mergedStr.substring(0, Math.max(0, mergedStr.length()-1));` is another option, albeit somewhat confusing, but the regex is probably simpler, though not everyone may understand regex.

Answer (score 1):

A useful pattern that I often use for this kind of thing is to append the first item, and then append the remainder of the items preceded by the separator.  This avoids unnecessary conditionals in loops or postprocessing to remove trailing separators.

I know, microoptimizations blah, blah, sixth circle of hell, blah, blah, but just including here for your amusement:

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(textStr);
    StringBuilder mergedStr = new StringBuilder();
    if (matcher.find()) {
      mergedStr.append(matcher.group());
      while (matcher.find()) {
        mergedStr.append(',').append(matcher.group());
      }
    }
    return mergedStr.toString();
```

Also, I'm not 100% convinced that replacing a quadratic algorithm (string concatenation) with a linear algorithm (`StringBuilder`) qualifies as a microoptimization in the bad sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "@awesome@dude";
        List<String> strSplit = new ArrayList<String>();
        String result = "";

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()){
            strSplit.add(matcher.group());

        }
        for(int j = 0; j< strSplit.size(); j++){
            result = result + strSplit.get(j);
            if(j < strSplit.size() -1){
                result = result+",";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
```